# Map 2 different objects with matching properties using lodash

Tags: angularjs, node.js, lodash

I am basically new to lodash but I know lot of such magics can be done easily with the help of lodash. So I am trying to use lodash here to map 2 different objects.

Here is my objects.

```
var obj_one = [{
  "username": "bob",
   "adminType": "facebook",
},
{
  "username": "tom",
  "adminType": "twitter"
},
{
  "username": "bob",
  "adminType": "twitter"
}];

var obj2 = {
  "bob": {
    "full_name": "Bob Something",
    "department": "Social Site",
  },
  "tom": {
    "full_name": "Tom Something",
    "department": "Networking Site",
  },
  "harry": {
    "full_name": "Harry something",
    "department": "Principal Engineering"
  }
}
```

In my result output, I want to append the department property to obj1, from obj2.

```
obj_result = [{
  "username": "bob",
   "adminType": "facebook",
   "department": "Social Site"
},
{
  "username": "tom",
  "adminType": "twitter",
   "department": "Networking Site"
},
{
  "username": "bob",
   "adminType": "twitter",
   "department": "Social Site"
}];
```

I think I can do this by looping through one of the object and somehow process the data. But if can be done through lodash that can be really very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using vanilla JS (or lodash's equivalent), you can use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate the array, and use [Object#assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to create new objects that contain the `department` property:

```js
var arr = [{"username":"bob","adminType":"facebook"},{"username":"tom","adminType":"twitter"},{"username":"bob","adminType":"twitter"}];

var obj = {"bob":{"full_name":"Bob Something","department":"Social Site"},"tom":{"full_name":"Tom Something","department":"Networking Site"},"harry":{"full_name":"Harry something","department":"Principal Engineering"}};

var result = arr.map(function(o) {
  return Object.assign({}, o, { department: obj[o.username].department });
});

console.log(result);
```